# Why does sparseness result in NMF solution?

Tags: matrices, statistics, dimensional-analysis

I am having trouble understanding the interpretation of a sparse matrix: I am studying Non Negative Matrix Factorization, and I noticed that, even without specifying any constraint, I often obtain sparse matrix. Is it linked to uncorrelated or correlated data? Why does it happen and what is the possible interpretation?

I thought it has something to do with "learning by parts", so that every vector can represent a particular feature of the data(for example, in images picturing faces every vector could represent a part of the face), but I am not totally sure.

Moreover,is there any additional advantage of having a sparse matrix as a solution, besides the computational one?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Valentina

EDIT1 The matrix to be factorized (X) has a client for every row and the variables (columns) are the number of a certain kind of products purchased by each client, one column for product. I ran a simple code using R (if you need it I can paste it, but I do not know if I can here), giving only the X in input, and I noticed that the results are sparse. I was wondering if there is a reason (maybe correlated data?) which may lead to this results.

PS I posted this same question on Stack Overflow, but a user suggested to post it here.

Comment: Sparse often means that a only small percentage of the entries of the matrix are non-0. Sparse matrices as solutions can have advantages as there are ways to require less storage for them. Sparse matrices used in solving problems can have usages as there exist many equation solving methods which run much faster if the involved matrices / vectors are sparse. Also storage requirements are much lower.

Comment: Yes, but besides the computational advantages, is there a reason for this result? I do not impose any constraint on the solution, so why does it happen?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to answer without any details of how you do the factorization. Could you update the question with details of what you do to obtain the sparse results?

Comment: Yes that kind of matrix is likely to be sparse and also related to statistical corellation in one way or another.

Comment: Ok, so if the data are correlated, the resulting NMF matrix is likely to be sparse? Is there a reason or an interpretation for this fact? Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the extreme case say someone buying beer **always** also buys chips and vice versa simultaneously, then we can theoretically replace with constant times a vector with 1 in the position of "beer" and "chips" and 0 otherwise, in practice replacing two columns by one column storing "did customer buy beer&chips?". But I can't saying anything in particular about what your algorithm does if I can't see it.